# How to get count of objects in a ManyToManyField with 'self' / its own model in django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, orm, many-to-many

I'm trying to implement a network where users can follow each other in django like so:

```
> class User(AbstractUser):
>     followings = models.ManyToManyField('self', related_name='followers', symmetrical=False)
```

So the `followings` field is going to contain all the users a user is following, and I would also like to be able to access all of the user's followers, thus the `related_name`.

My question is, if I have a user's username, how can I make a query to retrieve that user object, with the annotation of its number of followings and number of followers? Here's what I've tried:

```
data = User.objects.annotate(number_of_followers=Count('followers'), number_of_followings=Count('followings')).get(username=user)
```

It seems alright to me, but somehow it's showing values that doesn't match the real numbers as in the actual database, as I've checked using the django admin app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that combining multiple aggregations (in my case, Count) using annotate will yield wrong results, as recorded in the documentation:

> https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/aggregation/#combining-multiple-aggregations

Luckily, I can use the `distinct` parameter because I'm using Count. Here's the working line:

```
data = User.objects.annotate(number_of_followers=Count('followers', distinct=True), number_of_followings=Count('followings', distinct=True)).get(username=user)
```

Comment: Did you notice user is able to follow himself, if you did. What was your solution.